# how to wait for a rtf file to be created by an external program in c#

Tags: c#

I'm writing a c# program that waits for rtf files to be created by an external program and then manipulate them. I need a method to do waiting on a rtf file.
I've tried while loop but it decrease speed of the external program I think I should use FileSystemWatcher class, bit I don't know how to use it for rtf files.

Comment: It's just a file, like any other - why wouldn't `FileSystemWatcher` work? Give it a go, give it a try, then come back here if it doesn't work. =)

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to use it for rtfs or do you not know how to use `FileSystemWatcher` at all?

Comment: @Iman: You would use it the same as you would for any other file type as J. Steen said... What do you think are the problems with using it for RTFs?

Answer (score 2):

```
var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(yourDirectory, "*.rtf");
```

[MSDN FileSystemWatcher constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b30akzf.aspx)

This ought to get you started.  *I don't know how to use it* is a little too vague.  If you post some code as to what you've tried and why it isn't working like you'd expect, the community could give you a better answer.  Absent that, here's the [MSDN page for FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7t1d0ky) that has code you can experiment with.

Answer (score 1):

FileSystemWatcher seems well-suited. Just use it as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx and filter for your exact filename instead of "*.txt".

Answer (score 0):

```
System.IO.FileSystemWatcher watcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher(directory, file_name);
System.IO.WaitForChangedResult result;    
result = watcher.WaitForChanged(System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Created);
```